# Can a Modern UI app edit system files?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, microsoft-metro

Basically I am contemplating building a quick app to help me with setting up new sites for development, what I am wondering is if there is a permission you can give to Modern UI apps so they could edit the system hosts file?

Comment: I don't know if this question is on topic here, feel free to suggest a more appropriate exchange site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Look at this overview of [File and Access permissions in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

The system hosts file is not in one of these folders, it is normally located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`.

**EDIT**
Some extra advise: please have [a look at powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857337.aspx) in general a form of command or batch files is preferred over a graphical UI tool because it can be run without user interaction.

Comment: I added some advise to my answer